# Marking libraries as optional

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I have a small WinForms app (MyApp) in VisualStudio which references a WebAPI DLL (MyDLL).

MyDLL contains a reference to `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`, but the basic features also run fine without `ReportViewer` installed. Also, when deploying MyDLL onto an IIS server as a WebAPI IIS application, `ReportViewer` library is not required on that server. (instead, the features which require `ReportViewer` will throw runtime errors when they are invoked on servers that do not have `ReportViewer` installed.)

But when I publish MyApp ("ClickOnce deployment"?), and try to run the resulting setup  on client computers, it throws the error that `ReportViewer` has to be installed first.

How can I mark the `ReportViewer` library as an optional requirement in the setup?

Comment: I think we need more details - which project depends on which DLL, and how.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this article. http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/implementing-a-plug-in-architecture-in-c/184403942

Comment: If the code isn't relying on that dependency, why does it reference it?  Can you remove that reference?

Comment: @David I couldn't use the `ReportViewer` classes for development until I added that reference. They are in the code, just that most people won't call them, and they can still install the library if required.